# Plotting residuals above the fitted regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose that I have a scatter plot of points `(x_i,y_i)` and I want to plot the fitted regression line and then drop a line from each point to the line (in a different color) to show the residuals. How can this be done in R, preferably with ggplot?

Comment: see `?fortify`, `?geom_segment` ... have you made any attempts for yourself yet?

Comment: It would be helpful to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the code you're using to fit the model.

Comment: @BenBolker, Thanks, I haven't since ggplot2 does not seem to allow multiple plots on the same axis and I find the syntax in general very convoluted.

Comment: hmm.  Why then do you prefer ggplot2?

Comment: @BenBolker, Great! That seems to be what I was looking for. Re why I prefer `ggplot2`, I haven't yet made up my mind. Its plots look nicer out of the box, though it seems one has to go to great lengths to produce nonstandard plots. I am asking since I simply want to see how it is done with ggplot2, and whether it is worth investing time learning about it.